# What do you call the main area in an auditorium below the balcony?

Tags: word-request

[image]

What do you call the main area in an auditorium below the balcony? I am thinking "main floor" or "first floor", but it sounds not specific enough and I think there might be a better word for it. What would you call it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a theatre it's called the "stalls".
Ref: https://theatre.london/theatre-guide/beginners-guide-sit-theatre/

Answer (score 0):

In theater's that put on musicals or plays it would be called the ["Orchestra"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/orchestra) Section

> 2b: the forward section of seats on the main floor of a theater
>
> 2c : the main floor of a theater

But, in auditoriums like this one that wouldn't apply since there is no orchestra pit. I am not sure there is a generally accepted word, but there are common terms (including the ones you suggested) such as:

> First Floor
>
> Ground Floor (typically only if the main floor is on the same level as the ground)
>
> Main Floor
>
> Lower Level
>
> Bottom Floor

Comment: I think people would still call it "orchestra." Although venues can name things whatever they want really.